# R ggplot, reorder function mess color code of labels when confronted to same value

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, label, reorderlist

I have a problem with ggplot and colored labels

```
#example data:

names<-c("a","albert","aline","d","francis")
value<-c(11,10,9,9,21)
c<-c("black","red","red","black","red")

df<-data.frame(names,value,color)
```

I am trying to make a really simple barplot, with colored labels (here for the example labels that have firstname). It did this:

```
p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=reorder(names,value), y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
p+ coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 1,colour =  reorder(c, value) ))
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiDDY.png)

The "d" gets the red colot and not "aline". It looke like that, when confronted to same value, the `reorder` function sort the names by inversed alphabetical order. However, when ordering the colors, it looks like the function doesn't work the same, as it doesnt color the right label.

I think that way because if you change "aline" with "eric" (change the alphabetical order with "d") it works the correct way.

```
names<-c("a","albert","eric","d","francis")
value<-c(11,10,9,9,21)
c<-c("black","red","red","black","red")

df<-data.frame(names,value,color)
p<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=reorder(names,value), y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
p+ coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 1,colour =  reorder(c, value) ))
```

I hope this is clear, if somebody has an idea on how to fix this, you are more than welcomed

Comment: I recommand you not to label objects as they have the same names as already existing functions (here, `c` and `names`). This can create some issues as you call functions (example: `T <- FALSE 
isTRUE(T)
[1] FALSE`, while `T` is short for `TRUE` (`isTRUE(T)
[1] TRUE`))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the colours of labels through vectorised input to theme elements is not really supported. Instead, one can use the ggtext package to markup text with (some) html tags.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

names<-c("a","albert","aline","d","francis")
value<-c(11,10,9,9,21)
color<-c("black","red","red","black","red")

df<-data.frame(names,value,color)
df$xlabel <- glue::glue("<span style='color:{color}'>{names}</span>")

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=reorder(xlabel,value), y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Following @MonJeanJean's advice, I took the liberty to rename a few objects.

```
names <- c("a", "albert", "aline", "d", "francis")
value <- c(11, 10, 9, 9, 21)
colvec <- c("black", "red", "red", "black", "red")

dat <- data.frame(names, value, colvec)
```

The problem comes from the function `reorder`: applied on the colors, it would work only if there was one color per bar. The following will work on your example:

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = reorder(names, value), y = value, fill = I(colvec))) +
  geom_col() + 
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = colvec[order(value)]))
```